# Kafka Mongo Sink Connector Degraded due to port 8083

Tags: mongodb, docker, apache-kafka, connector, confluent-control-center

I am working on a Kafka/Mongo Docker Cluster i build with docker-compose.yml i was provided.

I have 5 container :

-Kafka

-Mongo: username:root pass : root

-Kafka-Connector

-Confluent Control Center

-ZooKeeper

I have created a "topic1" on Kafka, a mongo database "HopitalCardiaque" and a collection "MaladeUrgent".

My objective is to configure a Mongo Sink connector so that every data published on the topic is sink into a mongodb. I have already consult most post regarding the subject here without finding a solution.

I tried 2 methods: manual configuration with REST API and with Control center on localhost:9021.

Everytime i get from control center connector details:

**Connector Topic Degraded - Task : Status :Failed Task id : connect 8083.**

but when using curl localhost:8083 on the Kafka connector it is working and i get :

```
{"version":"5.3.0-ccs","commit":"a8eb7a79910d0f1a","kafka_cluster_id":"P-FBPW7aRQWAtBczUCLCpA"}
```

Here the config of the connector :

```
{
  "name": "topic1",
  "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "2",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "errors.retry.timeout": "-1",
  "topics": [
    "topic1"
  ],
  "connection.uri": "mongodb://root:root@mongo:27017/?authSource=admin",
  "database": "HopitalCardiaque",
  "collection": "MaladeUrgent"
}
```

I am adding the docker-compose.yml file here :

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.0
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:

      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'


  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.3.0.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
   
  control-center: ## API to examine kafka broker,topics and connectors
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:5.3.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - kafka 
      - connect
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
  
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2.2     
    hostname: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    command: [--auth]
```

And the Dockerfile :

```
 FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:5.3.0
 
 ENV  CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH:"/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components" \
 && CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.3.0.jar
 
 RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:latest
```

Comment: Okay, the server is running, but the connector isn't? Please show `curl localhost:8083/topic1/status`

Comment: {"error_code":404,"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}        but the topic is running on kafka with /usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --topic topic1 --broker-list localhost:9092

Comment: Edit : the problem was dumb. It seems the connector didn't want to accept a name with a interger in it. So when i change the topic name, it worked.

Comment: Numbers are valid within topic names. I think the problem is elsewhere. Connect is built upon the same consumer API that the console consumer uses

Comment: Connector Downgrade issue can also happen even when you send an empty record through Confluent Centre.

Comment: I absolutly have no idea what went wront. But after i changed the topic name to a topic without a number it just worked. So strange.